# create unique value and push to array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create a array with unique values. In here if the created value is include in that array, then need to create another value and again need to check that newly created value exists in that array, if again exists then need to do the same check.

Here is the code I have tried, if I execute this, I think infinite looping scene happening.

```
let arr = [];
for(let i=0; i<10;i++) {
  let k = 1;
  let pass = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 6 + 1)) + 6)+'a';
  while(k > 0){
    k++;
    if(arr.indexOf(pass) > -1) {
      pass = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 6 + 1)) + 6)+'a';
    } else {
      arr.push(pass);
      break;         
    }
   
    console.log(arr)
  }
}
```

What was the mistake in this code?

Comment: First of all, `(Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 6 + 1)) + 6)` will get you a number from 6 to 10 if I am not mistaken, second of all how would you want 10 unique items in an array if you generate on 5 unique ? Third of all, the problem is here `k > 0` it goes in an infinite loop.

Comment: Your third point is half correct. The only reason k>0 goes into an infinite loop is *because* it never hits the break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you're correct. It's an infinite loop.

The problem is the line `pass = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 6 + 1)) + 6)+'a';`. This will only ever generate one of 5 values. `pass` will only ever be

- 6a
- 7a
- 8a
- 9a
- 10a

Beause your array is 10 elements long, but you're only filling it with 5 possible elements, you will never be able to fill it with all unique elements. So it will go into an infinite loop trying to generate unique elements but never finding unique elements.

You need to rewrite the calculation of pass to generate more than 5 unique elements. Try `pass = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))+'a';` and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, My bad :D I got this number generating part for this example, and forgot to think about it's results

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [(Math.floor(Math.random() * (10)))+'a'];
 for(let i=0; i<=10;i++) {
   let k = 0;
    let pass = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (10)))+'a';
   while(k < arr.length){
       k++;
        if(arr.indexOf(pass) > -1){
            pass = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 6 + 1)) + 6)+'a';
        }else {
            arr.push(pass);
            break;
         }
        
  
     }


    }
    
    
    console.log(arr)
```

variable k is always > 0 in your condition and it loops infinitely.

edit 1:

answer updated based on @Mathew answer

Comment: This is half correct. It *would* drop out of the loop *if* it ever hit the break. The root of the problem is that it doesn't consistently hit the break.